# Is there a way to print at which point for loops ended?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a little thing here which checks if a number is prime or not:

```
num = int(input("Choose a number: "))

for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print("Not prime")
        break
else: print("prime")
```

What I would like to add is the output on which number the foor loop ended, so which number is the smallest divisor of `num`
Example: for `num = 8` it would be 2. For `num = 21` it would be 3

How can I implement that?

Comment: `print(i,"Not Prime")`? Nothing prevents you from printing `i` before you break. I don't see the difficulty.

Comment: Why not just print(i) ?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
for i in range(2, num):
    if num % i == 0:
        print(num, " is Not prime")
        print("Smallest devisor of num is = ", i)
        break
    else: 
        print("prime")
```